# Select2 plugin for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So I am using select2 for tags on my site but I want it to work a bit differently than is does currently. I want an input field that you insert that tags into but i want the tags to be displayed below the input once selected. I have added an image of Linkedin as they currently do this:

[image]

I cant seem to find any options within select2 that allow for this (If this is available and i have missed it then i apologies) So I was wondering if anyone on here knows if this is possible using select2 and if not is there another plugin that i would be able to this with? Checking before i start to right this from scracth!

Comment: Not sure if you can do that with Select2... You'll probably need to build it from the scratch (which might not be that hard, if you think about it). On another note, asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the off-topic question

Comment: you will have to have a separate input for that and use select2 methods to add tags